# Logon to a Website via Java

Tags: java, forms, authentication, web

I have been looking everywhere but could not find a tutorial for this. I want to make a simple way to login to a website's login form via java. I have no code so I was hoping one of you guys will have some example code for this; Or if you can redirect me to some website -- that'd be good too.

Question: How do I make a Java program to access a website's Login form and simply log on?

Reason I need this: I have code to login to a MySQL database but I wanted to try to login to a websites login form instead. WARNING: this is NOT for a school project at all. Just personal stuff

How much research have I done: I've looked for a couple weeks now and can't find much on this. Please help me; I'm in dire need of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment to Alexwho96's answer I guess you want to automate the login process to an existing login page.

AFAIK HtmlUnit should be able to do this (normally used for unit testing).

http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/

Edit:

You could also try:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html

I'm not sure if this works login forms, though.

Comment: Thanks but still.... I don't really want to download anything extra. I know there is a way without any libraries. I've seen it before but forgot what the page was at the time.

Comment: Well, libraries are not a "bad" thing. Especially well tested libraries means more stable code and less code to write and maintain for you. Otherwise you can have a look at the source code of HtmlUnit. It's Open Source.

Answer (score 1):

A login form collects some user input through an html form, probably a username and password, and sends this to the web server using http post. It is very easy to download the content of a web page with a java program; sending form data takes a little more work.
But the apache HttpClient makes it easy to send form parameters to a web site - like a login form. I think you can use it for your purpose:
 http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/

Here is an example using the above library to login to a web site:
 http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/http.client/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientAuthentication.java

Comment: You might want to make it clearer that the Java code won't actually interact with the login page, it will simply send a request similar to the requests that the login page makes. Just so the OP is clear on your answer.